# Sahasra Mukhi (Thousand Faced) Raavana Killed by Sita

Tags: scripture, ramayana, rama, sita

**Siya Ke Ram** is an Indian historical epic TV series on *Star Plus* produced by Nikhil Sinha. I'm talking about the episode telecast on 30 Aug 2016, which you can watch [here](http://www.hotstar.com/tv/siya-ke-ram/6363/sita-kills-sahastra-ravan/1000108461)

- [Here](https://twitter.com/SiyaKeRam_SP/status/770596560103206912?lang=en) you can see how Sita takes **Bhadra Kali Avatar**.

> Sahasra Mukha Raavana arrives to fight against Rama. Vibhishana says He(Raavana) is the eldest son of Kaikesi, she knew that he will be very dangerous and destructive, so she had immersed him at the time of his birth, his soul was protected. It seems she has revived him again by taking Pithashri's help. You have to kill him now.
>
> Rama says we all can kill Him together, and orders Sugreeva to attack him with entire Vanar sena from all four directions, Lakshmana attack from east, Angad from north side and Hanuman from sky route.
>
> All they run to attack Raavana but Raavana will hit them and they fall around. Lakshmana get hits by fire balls and fall. Hanuman flies and irritates him. Rama shoots at him but nothing happens. Raavan throws thunder light towards Rama. To protect Rama, Hanuman comes in between and hit by thunder bolt. Hanuman saves Rama but he falls down. Once again Raavana throws thunder bolt, Rama gets hit by that and falls down.

After this, Kaikesi informs Sita that how Raavana defeated Rama. Take a look how Rama and Vanar sena are laying unconscious.

> Sita goes to battle ground and sees all were fallen on ground including Rama, Lakshmana, Hanumana. Sahasthra Raavana laughs and She gets angry. She shouts and take **Bhadrakaali avatar** she comes infront of Raavan and gets ten hands and ten weapons. She starts attacking on him, and finally jumps on him and fire blast occurs. **Sahasthra Raavana gets killed by Bhadrakaali**.

Sita gets calmed down seeing Rama and cries. She gets back to her original form i.e., from Bhadrakaali to Sita.

Well, that was the story from TV series. I was wondering because I never heard this. However I think this episode has been banned because I couldn't find any video of that episode as I have mention.

My questions:

- In which scripture this story is described?
- Who is the author of that scripture?
- If it is mentioned in any scripture, then what is the actual description of this scene?

Comment: Ramayana is what made me interested in mythology, having read many different, i do recall my mother telling me about this. I [found this online](http://www.speakingtree.in/allslides/super-shocking-how-sita-saved-rama-and-killed-greater-ravana), will hopefully find the original scripture.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Thanks, it's more of a blog. We can not, and should not, treat this as a reliable source 0:)

Comment: This story is taken from [Adbuta Ramayana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adbhuta_Ramayana).. Adbuta Ramayan mainly highlights Sita and as that serial is mainly from Point of view of Sita (at least that's what they say), they might have picked stories from Adbuta Ramayana. I couldn't find any English version of Adbut Ramayana online, though English version is available [here](http://www.vedicbooks.net/adbhuta-ramayana-sanskrit-text-with-transliteration-english-commentary-alongwith-explanatory-notes-relevant-appendices-p-15944.html).

Comment: @TheDestroyer This look good, please write it as an answer.

Comment: @ABcDexter I don't have Adbut Ramayan to cite as reference.

Comment: serial is based on devdutt patnayak book , and this ravan is mentioned near to page number 330 in his book Sita an illustrated retelling

Comment: @TheDestroyer You would have answered it instead of comment. Thanks for the links :-)

Comment: @KrishnShweta I can't understand Hindi properly. So, i just left comment.

Comment: There are many kalps , and in every kalp same story is repeated , Ramayana was written before birth of ram.
In every kalp though it is the same story but many other incidents too take place.
While narrating the story some incidents get narrated from other kalp and get mixed.
Normally people know that $ita only once went to lanka. But she went four times only few knows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This story of Sita killing Sahasra Seersha ravana is not from the original Valmiki Ramayana, but a different version called Adbhuta Ramayana. Though Adbhuta Ramayana is attributed to Valmiki, it is not from original Valmiki but creation of someone else in the name of Valmiki ([Refer here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=CU92nFk5fU4C&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=adbhut%20ramayana%20writer&source=bl&ots=ZiVO9qINrp&sig=rJJa_MFE8kzYrFqK9exrHtYyHo4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjju7PoptjOAhWJPY8KHa6hBgIQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=adbhut%20ramayana%20writer&f=false) page 92 and 93.)

So, in Adbhuta Ramayana (Sanskrit Text with Hindi Translation is available [here](http://webstock.in/001-Epics-PDF/Adbhut-Ramayan-Hindi/002-Adbhut-Ramayan-Hindi.pdf) and [here](http://webstock.in/001-Epics-PDF/Adbhut-Ramayan-Hindi/001-Adbhut-Ramayan-Hindi.pdf). English Translation is available [here](http://www.vedicbooks.net/adbhuta-ramayana-sanskrit-text-with-transliteration-english-commentary-alongwith-explanatory-notes-relevant-appendices-p-15944.html).), Sarga 23 describes Sita killing Sahasra Mukha Ravana.

The context goes roughly like this

> After Sri Rama fell from Pushpak Vimana, all the creatures made
>   Hahakaar, the earth together with mountains, oceans and everything
>   started to tremble. Sages and Rishis shouted 'O Rama, O Rama'. Sahasra
>   Mukha Ravana with his followers started to dance in battlefield.
>   Comets and Asteroids fell from the sky and Everyone thought it is the
>   end of the world. Then the sages like Vasishta and everyone pleaded to
>   Sita what happened to Rama  and where are thother Vanaras and brothers
>   and everyone. Looking at all this and the pleadings of Rishis Sita
>   takes the form.

The important slokas regarding her form and her killing Ravana are mentioned here.

> नर्दन्तं राक्षसं चापि महाबलपराक्रमम् । साट्टहासं विनाद्योच्चैः सीता
>   जनकनंदिनी ॥
>
> स्वरूपं प्रजहौ देवी महाविकटरूपिणी । क्षुत्क्षामा कोटराक्षी
>   चक्रभ्रमितलोचना ॥
>
> Looking at the shouting valorous and strong Rakshasha, Janaka's
>   daughter Sita laughing out loudly leaving her svarup (present form of
>   Sita), took a very fearful form with a body (as if effected by
>   hunger), eyes like a tree's cavity, face revolving like a wheel.
>
> दीर्घजंघा महारावा मुंण्डमालाविभूषणा । अस्थिकिंकिणिका भीमा
>   भीमवेगपराक्रमा ॥
>
> खरस्वरा महाघोरा विकृता विकृतानना । **चतुर्भुजा** दीर्घतुंडा
>   शिरोऽलंकरणोज्जवला ॥
>
> ललज्जिह्वा जटाजूटैर्मण्डिता चण्डरोमिका । प्रलयांभोदकालाभा
>   घंटापाशविधारिणी ॥
>
> Her form is described as having large thighs, making a huge cry,
>   wearing a garland and ornaments of skulls, wearing small bells made of
>   bones, very strong, and with very great speed and valor, with very
>   sharp and focused cries, very horrible, with deformed face, having
>   **four shoulders**, with large mouth (or trunk), with a decorated head (meaning having a shining face), moving the tounge to and fro, with
>   matted hair, with fierce and hot body hairs, with light as that of
>   clouds at the time of Pralaya, wearing Ghanta and Paasha.
>
> अवस्कंद्य रथात्तूर्णं खड्गखर्परधारिणी । श्येनीव रावणरथे पपात
>   निमिषान्तरे ॥
>
> शिरांसि रावणस्याशु निमेषान्तरमात्रतः । खड्गेन तस्य चिच्छेद सहस्राणीह
>   लीलया ॥
>
> Got down very fast from chariot with sword and a bowl of skull got
>   upon Ravan's chariot in a minute like an eagle. Within a minute she
>   cut all the thousand heads of Ravan with sword like a sport.

After this, it is described how she destroyed other warriors also. Later 1000 matrikas arrive at the place and they all dance at her victory and she mentions some of the matrikas' names also. And the story continues.

Also it is clear that as shown in TV Serial she is **not ten handed** but with **four shoulders only**. Also if you read the story in the book, it will be clear that the story is somewhat manipulated in the TV Serial.

Hope this helps you.

PS: Thanks to [Sanksrit Dictionary](http://spokensanskrit.de/)

Comment: According to the link given by ABcDexter, it says, this happened after the Ram-Ravan war. When they are in Ayodhya. So, is it same?

Comment: @KrishnShweta It is before they left for Ayodhya. Look at the index in the document here http://webstock.in/001-Epics-PDF/Adbhut-Ramayan-Hindi/001-Adbhut-Ramayan-Hindi.pdf